# This method is not Implemented c#

Tags: c#, arrays, exception, user-input

I am new to c# and I'm writing for a budget app. I have my main class and my abstact class
here is my main class:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Calculate cal1 = new Calculate();

        cal1.getAmounts();
        
    }
```

and here is my expense class:

```
 abstract class Expense
{
    public abstract double getAmounts();

     public double grossIncome;



  public double estTax;
   public double rent;
    public double deposit;
   public float intRate;
   public double price;
   public int repayMonth;
        public [] monthExps = { "Groceries", "Water and Lights", "Travel costs", "Cell phone and telephone", "Other expenses" };
   

}
class Calculate : Expense
{
    public override double getAmounts()
    {
        

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Gross Income");
        string gI = Console.ReadLine();
        grossIncome = Convert.ToInt32(gI);
        Console.WriteLine("Groceries:" + "R" + grossIncome);

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Estimated Tax");
        string eT = Console.ReadLine();
        estTax = Convert.ToInt32(eT);
        Console.WriteLine("Estimated Tax:" + "R" + estTax);

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Groceries amount");
        string g = Console.ReadLine();
        monthExps[0] = Convert.ToInt32(g);
        Console.WriteLine(":" + "R" + monthExps[0]);

    }
}
```

My first issue is that i am trying to get user input for an array to store double values. Secondly my ***public overide double getAmounts*** has a red line beneath getAmounts.
my goal is to input values and output those values but when i run the code i get the
**System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.'**
on this line:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Groceries amount");
```

can anyone assist me with solving this error

Comment: did you check the compilation errors that you get?

Comment: In the following signature `public override double getAmounts()`, `double` is the return type of your method... But there is not a `return` keyword to be found in the implementation.. You either need one or change the method to void.

Comment: the whole code is weird for example : `public [] monthExps = { ..` should not compile.

Comment: @Self I have added the return value and the method is now giving me no errors. I also removed the `Console.WriteLine("Enter Groceries amount");
        string g = Console.ReadLine();
        monthExps[0] = Convert.ToInt32(g);
        Console.WriteLine(":" + "R" + monthExps[0]);`  from my code i am still doing some research on how to get user input for arrays

Comment: user input for arrays ? User can only input string. But he can type : "1,2,3,4,5,6" and you can split that on `','` and get an array of string. Then convert each of those string to get int array for example. `var myInts = Console.ReadLine().Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();`

Comment: But the whole abstract class and method is weird man. Just KISS. Work on your input work on the validation . Have simple method and real name for your variable.

Comment: user input for an array: first ask for "how many?", then create the array, then loop over it to fill it